# Logic Notation question (specifically about logical equivalences)

Tags: logic, notation

---

$$\text{Equivalence}$$

$p \land T \equiv p\tag{Identity law 1}$

$$p\lor F \equiv p\tag {Identity law 2}$$

$$p\lor T \equiv T\tag{Domination law 1}$$

$$p\land F \equiv F\tag{Domination law 2}$$

So, in the above image, where the T and F are, I assume these represent something like:
T = "any true proposition"
F = "any false proposition"

And so the first row in English would be "If P and any true proposition is true then this is logically equivalent to P" is that right? I could imagine it being something a bit different.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You're basically right, though I would very slightly change the wording:

Let $T$ be a true proposition. Let $F$ be a false proposition.

$p \land T \equiv p$: We interpret this as:

> The proposition "$p$ is true and $T$ is true" is equivalent to the proposition "$p$ is true."

$p \lor F \equiv p$: We interpret this as:

> The proposition "$p$ is true or $F$ is false" is equivalent to the proposition "$p$ is true."

$p \lor T \equiv p$: We interpret this as:

> The proposition "$p$ is true or $T$ is true" is equivalent to the proposition "$T$ is true."

$p \land F \equiv p$: We interpret this as:

> The proposition "$p$ is true and $F$ is false" is equivalent to the proposition "$F$ is false."

To see why this works, write out the truth tables of each proposition and see that the equivalences do hold.

Comment: Would it be okay to replace "is equivalent to" with "if and only if"?

Comment: @papercuts Yes. Those mean the same thing. (If it was useful please upvote! It's how we recognize good answers.)

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, $T$ = any proposition that is necessarily (or always) true (a *tautology*).
- And $F$ = any proposition that is necessarily (or always) false (a *contradiction*).
- The symbol $\;$"$\;\land\;$" denotes logical AND (conjunction).
- The symbol $\;$"$\,\lor\,$" denotes logical OR (disjunction).
- The symbol "$\;\equiv\,$" denotes "is logically equivalent to" or if you prefer, it denotes "*if and only if*".

*It might be helpful to review the truth-tables for the logical connectives $\land,\;\lor,\;\text{and}\;\equiv\;(\text{or}\;\iff)\;$ to understand *why* te following assertions must be true:

> $$p \land T \equiv p$$
>   $$p \lor F \equiv p$$
>   $$p \lor T \equiv T$$
>   $$p \land F \equiv F$$

With respect to your second question.

**Yes,** for the first identity, we have that $\; p \land T\;$ is logically equivalent to $\; p.\;$
Put differently: $(p\,$ AND  $\,T)\;$ *if and only if* $\;p$.

Since $T$ represents a tautology (true no matter what), then the truth-value of $\;p \land T\;$ depends *only* on the truth-value of $\;p\;$:
When $p$ is false both sides of the equivalence are false, and when $p$ is true, both sides of the equivalence are true.

So yes,

> $p \land T \equiv p$.

This also means $(p \land T \iff p):\quad$ ($p$ and $T$) if and only if $(p)$

Comment: how did this not get any votes? +1